# Android Studio: How do I remove the white background from my drawable, which is used to set the background of my button?

Tags: java, android

For example, here is an image from Google that has a white background, and I was wondering how I could remove it so that ONLY the white background is either completely gone, or transparent in my app.

Here is the link :

http://us.cdn3.123rf.com/168nwm/sarahdesign/sarahdesign1403/sarahdesign140300169/26672105-fast-forward-button.jpg

Comment: Question is not related to android. Anyway this may helpy you [link](http://www.freebackgroundremoval.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The first result from Google is this:

Make a color transparent http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0265.html

It makes the Blue part of an image transparent, but I'm sure you can adapt that to use White intstead

(hint: Pass Color.WHITE to the makeColorTransparent function, instead of Color.BLUE)

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101494/4874271)