# Java JPG To Png

Tags: java, image-processing, awt, image-editor

I am using a common format all over application for images as png.Any jpg image uploaded still gets saved as png using code as below.

```
java.awt.image.BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(jpgImagePAth);

 if(!IsExtensionPng(jpgImagePath)){
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File(pptFolder, justNamePng));
  }
```

But this preserves alpha even though it was not there in the jpg so makes a 2MB Image 7MB and 6MB to 16MB . Is there anyway to save png without maintaining the alpha ?

The reason I need to conver to PNG is that later on when I add text on image it looses the actual resolution. I already tried loseless JPEG which didnt fix it.

Comment: The "uploaded images", how would you use them? Depending on this answer I maybe can suggest something...

Comment: jpgImagePAth Thats where jpg image is already uploaded.

Comment: I mean, once they are uploaded and stored on the hdd. Is this for a desktop application? If so, explain a bit. Are you going to serve them over internet? How many images are we talking about? Would you use them a lot?

Comment: This is a web application.Yes I will be serving over internet. 800KB images becomes 1.5MB after saving as png .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the alpha channel that is causing the file size to grow, it's the file type.  JPG uses lossy compression; PNG is lossless compression.  In other words, JPG is throwing out some data to reduce the size of the file.  That's why you get to choose a "quality" level when saving to JPG - that determines how much is thrown out.

How do you know you're getting the alpha channel anyway?  If you still want PNG and want to be sure you're dropping the alpha channel, set the image type to BufferedImage.TYPE_RGB, e.g.

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_RGB);
```

You'll have to get the graphics object associated with your new BufferedImage and copy the jpg onto it, then write it out.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665406/how-to-make-a-color-transparent-in-a-bufferedimage-and-save-as-png) isn't quite the same as yours but has sample code you may find useful.

Paul

Comment: JPG image are not transparent. So when user uploads JPG i dont want to use alpha I think

Comment: +1 because the `BufferedImage` type seems the most likely culprit if there is an alpha channel being stored.  Sounds like OP probably has a good reason for choosing PNG.  Storage space is cheap, but it does seem silly to store an unused alpha channel.

Comment: Yes, I know JPG images are not transparent.  I was wondering why you thought the PNGs you were writing contained transparency information.

Comment: I mean whatever additional information is added when saving as png. Is there anyway I can turn that off ?

Comment: No, this answer explains that PNGs will ALWAYS be larger then the exact same image as a JPG. If you want to use PNG, you will have to be okay will the larger file sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly in what situation you are. But I should keep JPEG JPEG. The only advantage of converting JPEG to PNG is wasting hdd space.

Comment: I guess it was in the edit that was made after your answer, but preventing distortion artifacts around letters is a definite advantage of PNG compared to JPEG.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes that is definitely true. But that is an advantage of PNG, not an advantage of converting from JPEG to PNG.