# Two similar methods with BufferedImage, one working, one not. Why?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have tried to make method which changes one color of BufferedImage to be invisible.
I can't find solution myself so I ask for your help.
Here is method made by me:

```
public static BufferedImage makeWithoutColor(BufferedImage img, Color col)
{
    BufferedImage img1 = img;
    BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(img1.getWidth(), img1.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = img2.createGraphics();
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    g.drawImage(img1, null, 0, 0);
    g.dispose();
    for(int i = 0; i < img2.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; i < img2.getHeight(); i++)
        {
            if(img2.getRGB(i, j) == col.getRGB())
            {
                img2.setRGB(i, j, 0x8F1C1C);
            }
        }
    }
    return img2;
}
```

And here is one from tutorial i read.

```
public static BufferedImage makeColorTransparent(BufferedImage ref, Color color) {
    BufferedImage image = ref;
    BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    g.drawImage(image, null, 0, 0);
    g.dispose();
    for(int i = 0; i < dimg.getHeight(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < dimg.getWidth(); j++) {
            if(dimg.getRGB(j, i) == color.getRGB()) {
            dimg.setRGB(j, i, 0x8F1C1C);
            }
        }
    }
    return dimg;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error message? Have you tried just to copy/paste the tutorial and just change `image` to `img1`?

Comment: Ok so which one is working and which one not? And if one is working whats the problem/

Comment: Height/width in reverse order, could that be problem?

Comment: No, when i draw this image it simply looks like nothing was done with it, also the second one is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is this line:

```
for(int j = 0; i < img2.getHeight(); i++)
```

should be:

```
for(int j = 0; j < img2.getHeight(); j++)
//             ^                     ^ as Ted mentioned...
```

Comment: Probably should also be `j++`.

Comment: Thank you, what a shame i didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "invisible" you mean that you want to make one color transparent. You aren't going to be able to do it using this approach, because `setRGB` doesn't affect the alpha channel. You are better off using an image filter. Here's an approach taken from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665406/how-to-make-a-color-transparent-in-a-bufferedimage-and-save-as-png):

```
public static Image makeWithoutColor(BufferedImage img, Color col)
{
    ImageFilter filter = new RGBImageFilter() {

        // the color we are looking for... Alpha bits are set to opaque
        public int markerRGB = col.getRGB() | 0xFF000000;

        public final int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
            if ((rgb | 0xFF000000) == markerRGB) {
                // Mark the alpha bits as zero - transparent
                return 0x00FFFFFF & rgb;
            } else {
                // nothing to do
                return rgb;
            }
        }
    };
    ImageProducer ip = new FilteredImageSource(im.getSource(), filter);
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(ip);
}
```

This will turn any pixel with the indicated RGB color and any transparency to a fully transparent pixel of the same color.