# Removing transparency in PNG BufferedImage

Tags: java, png, bufferedimage

I'm reading a PNG image with the following code:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL(url));
```

Upon displaying it, there is a black background, which I know is caused from PNG transparency.

I found solutions to this problem suggesting the use of `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB`, however I am unsure how to apply this to my code above.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create a second `BufferedImage` of type `TYPE_INT_RGB`...

```
BufferedImage copy = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Paint the original to the copy...

```
Graphics2D g2d = copy.createGraphics();
g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE); // Or what ever fill color you want...
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, copy.getWidth(), copy.getHeight());
g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
g2d.dispose();
```

You now have a non transparent version of the image...

To save the image, take a look at [Writing/Saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)

Comment: I needed to draw the image to the entire rectangle, so basically filling it completely. Syntax slightly varies:


`g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, copy.getWidth(), copy.getHeight(), null);`

Comment: @JanPetzold The solution would depend on the requirements, personally, I use a "scale to fill" approach which maintains the aspect ratio of the original image, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928).  In most cases, the inbuilt scaling algorithms focus on speed over quality, so you should just be wary of that

Comment: This still blends the original source image onto the `copy `, so whatever background color you choose for `fillRect` will be partially visible on any pixel that wasn't completely opaque. Is there a standard way to ignore the alpha blending entirely and just assume all source pixels were completely opaque?

Comment: Short answer is no. The long answer is, you try different alpha blends