# Make background transparent in image.(Example image attached)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I remove white background color(white in this) from image?.
Or
Want to make image background transparent.

[image]

These are two images.
Image 1 is: Text with white background 
Image 2 is: Green(or close to green color) image

**I need to make white remove background transparent of image 1**

Comment: have you try @color/transparent ??

Comment: can you be more specific? do you want to do it only once? or do you want to do it programmatically for <any> image?

Comment: All images have same color pattern(black text and white background).I am reading these images from directory/folder and need to display on layout(that has green background)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an exampl](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0265.html)e to make `BLUE` color transparent in this image. [image]

> Here we have an Image with a blue background like  and we want to display it in an Applet with a white background. All we have to do is to look for the blue color with the "Alpha bits" set to opaque and make them transparent.

You can adapt it and make `WHITE` color transparent.

Also you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665406/how-to-make-a-color-transparent-in-a-bufferedimage-and-save-as-png).

Comment: this is not a full answer, this try to guide OP to goal... as far as there is no code provided, how can you be sure process converting image will be in android? maybe the image only has to be converted once... Also, is not impossible to convert this function from `java.awt` to `android.graphics`. Last but not least... feel free to post your own answer so we can help OP further :)

Comment: you are very right, the question does not provide many clues - i did transparency with like described in your answer - worked fine for me...

Comment: excuse me, when i was sounding harsh - i didn't meant to do so... sometimes that happens and i'm really sorry for that :-$

Comment: puh - when i did this, that was looooooong ago, i barely can remeber what i did then - the idea is to read an image into an buffer and then just walk over that buffer and edit each pixel...  afterwards create an file with your buffer...

Comment: cool that you are a tolerant man - i hope i'll be the same sometimes... (still working on it)...

Answer (score 0):

The question is that, you want to make background transparent at runtime or just this image? if just this one then you should edit the image with any tool like [irfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) to remove background color. just open this image in this tool and then save it as PNG and tick save transparent color and untick use window background color and then press enter. After that select white color.

Comment: i had the same idea, it's cheaper for beginners to edit the images manually than to write a rendering routine...

Comment: I want to make background transparent at runtime

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with photoshop.

Using the magic wand or lasso tool, select the area of the image you want to be transparent.
[image]

and then just hit DELETE button.

[image]

for additional information check this [link](http://www.mediacollege.com/adobe/photoshop/transparent/background.html)

you can also check this [tutorial](https://blog.udemy.com/photoshop-transparent-background/)

here is useful [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SV38L4c4JKY)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I want to make background transparent at runtime. I am rendering lot of images in android app. I am adding this in container at runtime. How can I do this pragmatically?

Comment: @smoke sorry, but I dont know how to do similar things in runtime =/

Answer (score 0):

when i had to solve that problem i used a buffer...

```
private IntBuffer buffer;
public void toBuffer(File tempFile){
    final Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgSource
            .getAbsolutePath());
    buffer.rewind(); //setting the buffers index to '0'
    temp.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
}
```

then you can simply edit all pixels (int-values) on your buffer (as mentioned from https://stackoverflow.com/users/3850595/jordi-castilla) ...
...setting ARGB for `0xFFFFFFFF` (white&transparent) to `0x00??????` (any color would suit, it's transparent anyway)

so here's your code to edit transparenty on a buffer:

```
public void convert(){
    for (int dy = 0; dy < imgHeight; dy ++){            
        for (int dx = 0; dx < imgWidth; dx ++ ){

            int px = buffer.get();
            int a = (0xFF000000 & px) >> 24;
            int r = (0x00FF0000 & px) >> 16;
            int g = (0x0000FF00 & px) >> 8;
            int b = (0x000000FF & px);

            int result = px;    

            if (px == 0xFFFFFFFF){ //only adjust alpha when the color is 'white'
               a = 0xFF000000; //transparent? 
               int result = a | r | g | b;
            }

            int pos = buffer.position();
            buffer.put(pos-1, result);
        }       
    }
```

later you want to write back your image into an converted file:

```
public void copyBufferIntoImage(File tempFile) throws IOException {
    buffer.rewind();
    Bitmap temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgWidth, imgHeight,
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    temp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    temp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

maybe you still want to know how to map a buffer?

```
    public void mapBuffer(final File tempFile, long size) throws IOException {

    RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile(tempFile, "rw");
    aFile.setLength(4 * size); // 4 byte pro int
    FileChannel fc = aFile.getChannel();
    buffer = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, fc.size())
            .asIntBuffer();

}
```

Comment: maybe i'm mixing up the color model, i can't remember if 100% opaque=`0xFF??????`or 100%opaque=`0x00??????`

Comment: so you have to edit the color values for yourself - maybe you want to use any other color as transparent... i'm pretty sure coloring isn't your actual problem ^^